# What's the rationale behind C's <stdlib.h> as opposed to including these functions by default?

Tags: c, programming-languages, language-design

Every program written in C that I've ever seen `#include`s `<stdlib.h>`, at least indirectly. You can't really do much useful without it.

Why aren't its functions just part of "standard C"?

Why should I have to `#include <stdlib.h>` before `malloc()`ing something?

Comment: Ever done any embedded programming ?

Comment: @bdonlan: I guess it's a toss up between "not a real question" and "not constructive" ?

Comment: You can write programs without requiring stdlib. Some areas (like software for powerstations/space crafts) you are not allowed to use `malloc`. There are ways around that.

Comment: This is a completely real question—I'm thinking about language design.

Comment: @PaulR, I feel this is borderline enough that close votes should at least have some attempt at justification attached...

Comment: They are part of standard C. The way to use a function in C is to provide a prototype for it. C placed its standard functions in various standard headers, which is made available to you through the standard include directive in C. Many programs and libraries can be made without the use of stdlib.h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C language was designed, from the start, to be used both in ordinary applications (running in a 'hosted environment') and OS kernels (and other specialized environments, running in a 'freestanding environment'). In the latter, ordinary C library functions like `malloc()` may be unavailable.

In order to allow the same compiler to be used for both hosted and freestanding environments, library functions are not hardcoded into the compiler, but rather are placed into header files loaded by the compiler - such as `stdlib.h`. OS kernels and other specialized programs do not (and cannot) include these standard headers.

Comment: Another common case are embedded platforms, with a severely reduced or different "standard" library.

Answer (score 8):

C is a minimalistic language. There are no built-in functions.

Answer (score 2):

Not all programs need to call `malloc()`. And those that do need dynamic memory allocation may prefer to do it a different way. C does not try to force a single way of working on programmers.

Answer (score 1):

This is still a perfectly valid program that doesn't require libc and can do much stuff apart from interfacing with the underlying operating system:

```
int main (void) {
  int x = 2;
  int y = 3;
  return x + y;
}
```

Comment: A better example might be a purely computational *translation unit* meant to be used as part of larger programs.

Answer (score 0):

One reason I can think of is that by putting the stdlib functions into a library, they exist in their own namespace, making it easier to overload them.

It might sound a little crazy to think of overloading malloc, but it's one way to implement a resource buffering system that might be used for say... dynamically creating game objects during a game loop without triggering allocations. You can preallocate a buffer, then overload  malloc to create the objects into the buffer rather than allocating new memory for them.

Comment: ITYM **override**, not *overload*.

Comment: C does not support overloading or overriding functions. Defining your own external function by the name `malloc` invokes undefined behavior.